# Compiling Oracle Views when someone is using it

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it correct that if I recompile my Oracle Views when someone else is running it, the DB would get "blocked"?

If yes, this is UAT DB and I do this (prefer to) regularly while potentially lot of users could be using it, so I wonder what is the right pattern to follow here? Pick a time when no one else is possibly using it? There is no fool proof way to determine that though.

Same issue with PROD too, although we recompile it during set down times.

Comment: So the real question here is "why are you recompiling views"? They should not need to be compiled. Oracle will automatically mark them invalid if anything referenced by them changes, then they will automatically compile the next time someone tries to access it. If this situation happens during heavy load, you could see a huge backup waiting for the view to get compiled. I've seen it before. Best is to leave the views alone (this is the same with synonyms and packages as well).

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an individual `view` currently being complied or not, this `sql` can be used :

```
select sign(count(1))
  from gv_$sql_bind_capture b 
    inner join gv_$session s on ( b.sql_id = s.sql_id )
 where b.name = ':OBJECT_NAME'
   and s.status = 'ACTIVE' 
   and b.value_string = upper('&i_view_name'); -- when prompted enter your view name (no need to be case sensitive)
 /
```

If you get `1`, then its being `compiled`.

If you get `0`, `NOT compiled`.

To see all views being compiled currently, use :

```
select b.value_string object_name
  from gv_$sql_bind_capture b 
    inner join gv_$session s on ( b.sql_id = s.sql_id )
    inner join dba_objects o on ( o.object_name = b.value_string )    
 where b.name = ':OBJECT_NAME'
   and s.status = 'ACTIVE'
   and o.object_type = 'VIEW';
```

> where corresponding literal `VIEW` for `o.object_type` may be replaced
>   with `PACKAGE`, `PACKAGE BODY`, `TRIGGER`, `PROCEDURE` or even
>   `TABLE`.

P.S. if you prefix data dictionary views with `g` as in `gv_$sql_bind_capture` or `gv_$session` instead of `v_$sql_bind_capture` or `v_$session`, you may use them for a `RAC` database.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can `alter view viewname compile` while a query of that view is running. (This might be version-dependent - checked in Oracle 12.1).

I'm not sure what the use case is here, though. Why does a view need compiling? If it's invalid, then how are users querying it?